# ElasticSearch Facets

Tags: elasticsearch

I have following elastic search query

```
SearchResponse response = DbContext.INSTANCE.client()
            .prepareSearch(indexList)
            .setTypes("docs")
            .setSearchType(SearchType.DFS_QUERY_THEN_FETCH)             
            .setQuery(queryBuilder)             
            .setFilter(FilterBuilders.andFilter(f1, f2))
            .addFacet(FacetBuilders.termsFacet("f").field("frm").size(10))
            .setFrom(pageNumber).setSize(size).execute().actionGet();
```

Facet count return by this query is global, how to get the facet for the search response?

---

I found the answer: What I done is add filter to the main query

```
QueryBuilder queryBuilder = QueryBuilders.boolQuery()
.must(QueryBuilders.queryString(criterion.getFullText()).field("text"))
.must(QueryBuilders.termsQuery("from", criterion.getFrom().toArray((new String[0]))))
.must(QueryBuilders.termsQuery("to", criterion.getTo().toArray((new String[0]))))
.must(QueryBuilders.rangeQuery("date").from(dtf.print(criterion.getFromDate())).to(dtf.print(criterion.getToDate())));

SearchResponse response = 
DbContext.INSTANCE.client()
.prepareSearch(indexList)
.setTypes("docs")
.setQuery(queryBuilder)
.addFacet(fb)
.addFacet(tf)
.addSort("date", SortOrder.DESC)
.setFrom(pageNumber).setSize(size).execute().actionGet();
```

Comment: If you want to filter a specific facet that's the way to go, but if you want to apply the same filters to both facets and search results, look up the filtered query. The top-level filters are applied only to the search results. Maybe it's better to add your answer as an answer to your question.

Answer (score 1):

This is what i did unless you want "main" search and facet has different search requirement.
`global=false` should do the trick for you

```
"facets": {
  "volume_by_day": {
    "date_histogram": {
      "field": "crdate",
      "interval": "day"
    },
    "global": "false"
  }
}
```